# I am having a problem with checking if my users are signed in to Firebase and changing the the initial view controller

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

My goal is to check if my users have signed in to my app in Firebase before. Then change the initial view controller from my `Navigation controller` to my `TabBarController`. I'd like to do this for a better user experience so they don't have to log in every time.

Also where is the best place to put this code? my first View controller or my app Delegate?

```
if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
        // User is signed in.
        func transitionToTab() {

            let tabBarController =
                storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.TabBarController) as? TabBarController

            view.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
            view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        }
    } else {
        // No user is signed in.
        func tranitionToView() {

            _ =
                storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.HomeViewController) as? ViewController

            view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

  }
}
```

Comment: Also I'm getting a error dealing with my tab bar 'storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.TabBarController) as? TabBarController' Error "Use of undeclared type 'TabBarController'"

Comment: You're not calling the functions anywhere

Comment: @HarryJ I didn't show it. func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you don't call the functions within the `if/else` statement.

I would recommend creating an additional slash screen that replicates the one within `launchscreen.storyboard` to initiate your authentication process. Your code should look similar to this;

```
if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            // User is signed in.
            let tabBarController =
                storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.TabBarController) as? TabBarController

            view.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
            view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        } else {
            // No user is signed in.
            storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.HomeViewController) as? ViewController

            view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> you can use this function from app delegate method
>   "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions"
>               and make an userdefaults to store current user object or any check that you
>                will true once user login into the app and in Appdelegate "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" 
>               check if it's true than set initial page
>               tabbarcontroller else show login screen.